# How do Java Futures work compared to other languages async features?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, async-await

**Some background:**

I have a task that consists of independent pieces, basically a for-each loop over key-value pairs that get processed. Usually between 10 and 30 of them. If the cache is empty, there will be a bunch of requests to another service *per piece*, resulting in a large amount of requests. With the cache being empty, it takes ~20 seconds. With a full cache, it is done in under a second (feels immediately, didn't measure).

I want to use asynchronous code to speed things up also for the empty cache cases, so I looked into Java Futures and am a bit overwhelmed. I see a lot of examples, but I am missing the important understanding how things work, even though I know Futures from other languages. The examples are typically a simple, blocking function call.

We currently use Java 17 and Spring Boot (currently v2, migration to v3 is ongoing), but I am happy with newer language features as long as they compile down to something that runs on a Java 17 runtime.

**The question:**

When it comes to real tasks, I had in other projects/languages often the case of having async function calls within other async function calls. How would I do this in Java? Do I need an async HTTP client in order to gain some performance, or does Java do its magic with blocking code? Do I have to submit internal Futures to an Executor? Can it be the same of the parent future? What is the most modern way with the least boilerplate code? How does this relate to async-await syntax in other languages?

Async works a bit different depending on the language, and for some reason I did not find any detailed information about this. Also, it is hard for me to distinguish outdated from up-to-date information in the Java world. I feel the question is pretty stupid, but I did not manage to find much useful information in the large amounts of blog posts out there.

Comment: Did you look at CompletableFuture? That'll cover most basic use cases. If you need more fine-tuning, you can use a custom Executor or maybe a ForkJoinPool (if tasks are recursive).

Comment: I saw it, but the documentation does not answer my questions. It is the most modern way to do it in java?

Answer (score 2):

```
       You can use completable future to call the 
       service and collects its response / returned data asynchronously

       Map < String, List<Object>> map //map with populated             values

       Map < String, List<Object>> responseMap =     map.entrySet().stream()
.collect(Collectors.toMap(
    Map.Entry::getKey,
    entry -> {
        List<Object> objects = entry.getValue();
        List < CompletableFuture<Object>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Object object: objects) {
            futures.add(service.asyncMethod(object));
        }

        return futures.stream()
            .map(CompletableFuture::join)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
));

   // asyncMethod in any service 

   @Async
 public CompletableFuture<Object> asyncMethod(Object object) {
// do some asynchronous processing
return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(response);
   }
//custom thread pool
   @Aynsc in spring uses a default thread pool with single
thread if we don’t specify the thread pool. To execute it  on multiple threads custom thread pool should be created and  add it in @Async annotation.

    1. Create a configuration class that implements AsyncConfigurer with @EnableAsync and @Configuration.
    2. Override getAsyncExecutor()
    3.define ThreadPoolTaskExecutor with core size, max size of threads and queue capacity and set any name to thread “myThread” and initialize() it.

    @Aynsc(“myThread”) to be used in annotation if custom thread pool is used

  The asynchronous processing in Java is similar to other languages. 
1. In other language Async tasks, it’s executed in non blocking way. The main thread is not blocked till the execution completes. 
Java Futures are blocking by default , but non blocking way can be achieved by using Completable Future.
```

Comment: Hi, I think if your answer would be really useful, but I am currently on mobile and not able to fix the broken formatting to fully understand it.  I am confused about the "Futures are blocking by default" part, but I assume you mean that they are object that can be polled by executors, similar to Futures in Rust? That would mean that CompletableFutures somehow are magic sugar that eases things, I guess?

Comment: Yes both Future and Completable Future can submit tasks to the executor that will perform an operation and return a result. The result obtained by calling get() on the Future, will block until the task is complete and the result is available.
Whereas the Completable Future uses the .join() method which is similar to .get() but it doesn't block the calling thread. 
CompletableFuture is more flexible version of Future with additional methods and features.